# How should I write tests for a Controller that returns a nondeterministic result for a GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

Let me present my problem into the simplest example I can come up with that is somewhat similar.

1. I have a database table "Article" with an integer attribute named "weight" and a string attribute named "name"
2. I have 10 Articles in the database with varying weights and names
3. I get a GET request that includes "name" as the parameter
4. Among the 10 Articles, I find the Articles with the same name. I found 4 Articles.
5. Among the 4 Articles, I choose one that is randomly chosen, but the randomness is weighted where a higher weight gives a higher chance of being chosen. So if the four weights are 1,3,5,7. I generate a random number between 0 and the sum of the weights (which is 1+3+5+7=16), and use that number to decide which Article is selected. So if the random number I got was 0, then I select the first Article. If the random number I got was 1~3, I select the second Article. If the random number I got was 4~8, I select the third Article. If the random number I got was 9~15, I select the fourth Article.
6. I send that Article as a response for the GET request.

As you can see, the response to a GET request with a specific "name" as parameter would not always be the same. However, all examples I find about testing Controllers rely on the response of the request being deterministic.

So I'd like to get some help on how I would go about designing my test code for this.

My current thoughts for tests are as following:

1. In terms of the response for the GET request, if the GET query does not include the name parameter, then I expect a HTTP Status code of 400 with a message "Bad parameters"
2. If the GET includes the name parameter, then I expect a HTTP Status code of 200 (but don't do any additional checks on the content)
3. If the GET includes a name that does not match with any of the Articles, then I expect a HTTP Status code of 200 and "null" as the response message.
4. I do a GET request with a name, I get the correct list of Articles that matches the "name" before I do the random selection.
5. I create 4 Article objects with the same "name" and each with weight 1,2,3,4 (sum of 10) respectively. I do 10,000 runs on the logic that does the weighted random selection. I check if the number of times I get the first Article is between 700 to 1300 (about 1/10 of 10,000), if the number of times I get the second Article is between 1700 to 2300 (about 2/10 of 10,000), if the number of times I get the third Article is between 2700 to 3300 (about 3/10 of 10,000), if the number of times I get the fourth Article is between 3700 to 4300 (about 4/10 of 10,000).

One problem is that despite trying to read on how to write tests on Ruby on Rails, I'm still not exactly sure how to do 4 and 5. 4 and 5 requires that I test things "within" the logic (instead of using the result of executing the entire logic). It seems like I need to break down the logic in smaller functions that can be called for testing 4 and 5. Is that correct? What else are things I should be testing?

Here is a simple code I created so that we can follow along for this example. The full code is here: https://github.com/maruhanpark/example

You can run it with docker compose.

The tests I explained above looks like the following in code:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ArticleControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "having no name parameter returns Bad Parameters" do
    get "/article"
    assert_response(400)
    assert_equal "{\"message\":\"Bad parameters\"}", @response.body
  end

  test "having name parameter returns 200" do
    get "/article?name=Bob"
    assert_response(200)
  end

  test "having empty name parameter returns 200 and null" do
    get "/article?name="
    assert_response(200)
    assert_equal "null", @response.body
  end

  test "getSelectedArticles returns the correct list of articles" do
  end

  test "randomWeight selects properly based on weight" do
  end
end
```

As you can see, I wrote the cases for the first three I explained, but left out cases 4 and 5.

For the Controller, I split off the logic that I want to test as separate methods. The two methods I created are each for the test cases 4 and 5. I'm not sure if it's necessary for me to create separate methods to test that logic.

```
class ArticleController < ApplicationController
    def getSelectedArticles(name:)
        #logger.debug "===== #{Article.where(name: name)}"
        return Article.where(name: name)
    end

    #Returns the index of the finally selected article
    def randomWeight(articles:)
        sum = 0
        articles.each { |a| sum += a.weight }
        randNum = rand(sum)
        returnIndex = 0
        for i in 0 ... articles.size
            randNum -= articles[i].weight
            if (randNum < 0)
                returnIndex = i
                break
            end
        end
        return returnIndex
    end

    def article
        if params[:name]
            selectedArticles = getSelectedArticles(name: params[:name])
            finalArticle = selectedArticles[randomWeight(articles: selectedArticles)]
            render json: finalArticle, status: :ok
        else
            render json: {message: "Bad parameters"}, status: :bad_request
        end
    end

end
```

One problem I'm facing for trying to implement test 4 is that I need to somehow get the code to have a breakpoint on the getSelectedArticles method after calling GET. I'm not sure if that's possible, or if I have to test it only as sort of a unit-test where I'm specifically calling the method and seeing that the method returns the expected thing.

Comment: This isn't actually specifically about controllers. Testing non-deterministic code in general is a hard problem and there are generally two solutions. 1. Make the code deterministic by stubbing out the random parts.  2. Test around the randomness of the code. Like for example testing that X number of the given sample are present but not making any assumptions about their order.

Comment: There really is a lot you can do here when it comes to the testability of this code and thats covered pretty well by Adit's answer. But where you're really going wrong here is that you're just splitting off the code into more methods in the same object. And that object is the controller which cannot be tested in isolation. Remember the SRP.

Answer (score 1):

I read your quest and noted the following things we could be improving on your  code:

1. Please use RESTful routes, ie in your `routes.rb` please write `resources :articles, only: [:show]`, have your controller called `ArticlesController` (note the plural) and your route will be `/articles/:id`
2. Please use two space indentation and snake_case for method and variable names
3. Use of `private` is encouraged to separate methods
4. No need for "return" on method's last statements
5. Selecting the random article in ruby might not be really performant if you have a lot of articles, I'd recommend doing it on the database: it'd be a bit more work on SQL skills but but it would be faster and scale better
6. I would encourage you to separate the controller stuff from your service so it's easier to test and develop

```rb
class SearchArticles
  def call(params)
    # All your logic here
  end
end

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def article
    render json: { message: 'Bad parameters' }, status: :bad_request unless params[:name].present?

    final_article = SearchArticles.new.call(params)
    render json: final_article, status: :ok
  end
```

Anyway here's my first pass of improvements:

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def article
    render json: { message: 'Bad parameters' }, status: :bad_request unless params[:name].present?

    selected_articles = search_articles(name: params[:name])
    final_article = selected_articles[random_weight(articles: selected_articles)]
    render json: final_article, status: :ok
  end

  private

  def search_articles(name:)
    Article.where('name LIKE ?', name)
  end

  def random_weight(articles:)
    sum = articles.pluck(:weight).sum
    rand_num = rand(sum)
    return_index = 0
    # This could be improved!
    for i in 0...articles.size
      rand_num -= articles[i].weight
      if (rand_num < 0)
        return_index = i
        break
      end
    end
    return_index
  end
end
```

## The test

As I don't know much about minitest, I'll write my answer for RSpec in hope you'll be able to convert it on your own (warning, untested!):

```rb
describe ArticlesController do
  describe '#article' do
    before do
      create(:article, id: 11, name: 'Bob 11', weight: 1)
      create(:article, id: 22, name: 'Bob 22', weight: 3)
      create(:article, id: 33, name: 'Bob 33', weight: 5)
      create(:article, id: 44, name: 'Bob 44', weight: 7)
    end

    it 'returns the correct article' do
      {
        0 => 11,
        1 => 22,
        3 => 22,
        4 => 33,
        8 => 33,
        9 => 44,
        15 => 44,
      }.each do |random_number, expected_article_id|
        allow_any_instance_of(Object)
          .to receive(:rand).and_return(random_number)

        get "/article?name=Bob"

        result = JSON.parse(response.body).id # please continue from here
        expect(result).to eq(expected_article_id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Please note none of above is in great shape, it should be taken just as a good starting point.

Best of luck mate!

Comment: This is an excellent answer. However you're kind of wrong about #1. `GET /articles?name="bob"` isn't necissarily the same thing as `GET /articles/bob`. In the first case its showing an index filtered by optional parameters and the second case its implied that there is only one user named `bob`.

Comment: You are right (and thanks) it should be probably even `/articles/random_article?name=bob` or something. Anyway there are a ton of fixes needed to be done but OP doesn't seem super involved himself. Should we then? 